# using winpdb to debug remote scripts

Tags: python, debugging, winpdb

I'm trying to debug a python script in a remote machine using winpdb.

The thing is that I want to run rpdb2 (the console version of winpdb) to launch the server in my remote machine to run the script.

Then, here at my local machine, I want to launch winpdb as a client to connect to the rpdb2 server to debug locally.

I managed to do the trick when in localhost, like:

server: 'remote' (but running in localhost):

```
screen rpdb2 -s -d -r script.py
```

client: 'local' (also in localhost):

```
winpdb -olocalhost -a script.py
```

This works fine. Now I just used the same server line in the remote host machine, and changed the client line -o option with the server address. BUT, now in my client, winpdb says it can't find script.py to attach to. Is there anything I should consider first to get it done?

Comment: got it, sorry! - in the server I got another incompatible version of winpdb than on the client. Using the same version solves the problem!

Comment: Could you please provide your comment as an answer instead of providing an answer in a comment. Now others, when searching for old, unanswered questions will find your question again. You could, and probably should, even mark that answer as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a mistake on my side.

In the server I got another incompatible version of winpdb than on the client. Using the same version solves the problem!

Comment: of course! don't forget to check your firewall on the server! rpdb2 uses port 51000 (TCP) by default. Check http://winpdb.org/docs/requirements/ for more info